# cakephp resultset for multiple joins and aggregate function...i.e. complex queries

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp in one of my project. What i need is to handle complex query using single model and single array out.Since I am new to cakephp i got stucked really very bad here :

```
$rs = $this->User->query("
                SELECT  (wd.wajebaat_amt) as commited,
                SUM(pd.sila_waje) as paid, 
                (wd.wajebaat_amt-sum(pd.sila_waje)) as balance, 
                FROM wajebaat_details as wd
                LEFT JOIN waje_pay_details as pd ON (pd.waje_id=wd.waje_id) 
                WHERE wd.hof_id="123" and wd.year="2010"
                GROUP BY wd.waje_id");

print_r($rs); exit();
```

// it displays output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wd] => Array
                (
                    [commited] => 252000
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [paid] => 253829
                    [balance] => -1829
                )

        )

)
```

//however i need it following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wd] => Array
                (
                    [commited] => 252000
                    [paid] => 200000
                    [balance] => 52000
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hash (utility) method format() in cakephp 2.5 to convert the nested array into string,in previous version of cakephp the method is  set(),

```
Hash::format(array $data, array $paths, $format)
```

Example :

```
$result = Hash::format($rs,array('{n}.wd.commited','{n}.wd.0.paid','{n}.wd.0.balance'),'%1$d,%2$d,%$d');
```

Output:

```
252000,2000000,52000
```

For More formating option refere [cook book of cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)